# read image from assets folder / sub package android studio kotlin

Tags: android, image, kotlin, assets, gradle-submodule

I have a situation where I need to read an image file (jpg) in a submodule.
The class where I need access to that image is a normal class. So I have two options.

1. I put that image in the asset folder and try to use assetManager, which doesn't work because I don't have context. My project doesn't have any activity or fragment, because it's a submodule
2. I put that image in a package. How can I access that image?

The code was written in kotlin.

I will be appreciated any help or suggestions

Comment: "My project doesn't have any activity or fragment, because it's a submodule" -- have something that calls functions in your submodule provide you with the `Application` singleton.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not sure if I understand. From Application singleton can I get access to the asset folder? And how can I do that?

Comment: `Application` is a subclass of `Context`, so you call `getAssets()` on the `Application` to get the `AssetManager`.

Comment: Oh right. I didn't see that getAssets() method from Application before because I use "." instead of "()."  I'm so dumb >.<. Thank you